# Is there a way to incrementally write to an image file to avoid running out of RAM when rendering a large image?

Tags: java, image

Currently I am running out of RAM when rendering images and while I have optimized it as much as I can for memory efficiency, I have realized that for images as large as I want it will never be enough so instead I want to write to a file as I am rendering. I have no idea how I could do this and I'm almost certain that most image formats won't be suitable for this as to recalculate compression they would need to put the image being appended to into RAM.

This is my current code. I'm happy to completely switch libraries to get this to work.

```java
panel.logic.Calculate(false); // Renders the image - I can make this render in steps

Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
panel.paint(g2d);
g2d.dispose();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss");
Date date = new Date();
File file = new File(formatter.format(date) + ".png");
try {
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file);
} catch (IOException ioException) {
    ioException.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't know what panel is/does, but do you have two copies of the image, one in panel and one in bufferedImage?

Comment: As an aside… If this is for on-screen display, perhaps you could reduce the size and density of the image?

Comment: By the way, you’re using legacy date-time classes. `OffsetDateTime.now().format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ).replace( "T" , "_" ).replace( ":" , "-" )`

Comment: What is the size of the image, and where is the failure?

Comment: What is the line where the OutOfMemory is fired ? `ImageIO.write(...` ?

Comment: The question is almost impossible to answer, since none of the readers can know what happens in the `Calculate` method. The best would be a minimal reproducible example and maybe some info about the environment (Java version, amount of ram etc), see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: The question isn't asking how to optimise the code but rather how to write images to files incrementally, if that is possible at all - RAM amount and how efficiently it is used is irrelevant. As for reproducibility from what I've managed to find this library doesn't support incrementally writing images to files so I'm looking for the IO part of the code to be completed replaced, not modified

Comment: If an image is so huge it doesn't fit in memory, a viewer won't be able to load it anyway. So what's the practical use of such an image?

Comment: Machine with less memory creating it for a machine with more, not wanting to use all of the system's memory while creating it etc

Comment: It's not incemental, but would using a memory-mapped file buffer instead of heap memory for the `BufferedImage` (avoids OOME) solve the problem?

Comment: How does the "machine with less memory" get hold of the image? The image must be read from somewhere or must be sent to the machine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in several image formats, but won't be easy with the standard Java Graphics2D api. In particular, the class `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` explicitly represents an image where the entire bitmap is held in memory.

I would start by asking, how large are the images you are thinking of here? Unless your generating program is unusually memory constrained, then any image that is too big to hold in memory during generating will then be too big to hold in memory during display, so would be useless, I think?

In order to write an image file in a "streaming" style, you will need a format that allows you to write pixels or regions. This will be hard in image formats that are more sophisticated like JPEG, but easier in image formats that are more pixel oriented like BMP or PNG.

For BMP, you would need to write the file header, then stream out the pixel array into the file, which you could do pixel-by-pixel without holding the whole thing in memory, then write the footer. The format is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

For PNG, it would be much the same, except that the file format is quite a bit more complicated and involves a compression layer (which can still be handled in a streaming format).

There aren't many libraries to handle this approach, because of the obvious limitations I outlined above and that other commenters have outlined: if an image is so large that it needs it, then it will be too large to ever display it.

I think you might be able to persuade `ImageIO` to write a BMP or PNG in a streaming fashion if you implement a custom `RenderedImage` class. I might see if I can get that to work; I'll update here if so.

### Example code

I had a go at writing a PNG image in a streaming fashion using `ImageIO`.
Here's the code:

https://gist.github.com/RichardBradley/e7326ec777faccb9579ad4e0b0358f87

I found that the PNG encoder will request the image one scanline at a time, regardless of the Tile settings of the Image.
See `com/sun/imageio/plugins/png/PNGImageWriter.java:818`

(This may in fact be a bug in PNGImageWriter, but no-one has noticed because no-one writes images in a streaming style in real world use.)

If you want to stream the data pixel-by-pixel instead of line-by-line, you could fork `PNGImageWriter` and refactor that section. I think it should be quite possible.

(I am not 100% certain that something inside the ImageIO / PNGImageWriter pipeline will not just buffer the image to memory anyway. You could turn the image size right up and retest to be sure.)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is *not* that the final image may not fit in memory.

The problem is that the rendering process takes too much memory.

This means that you have to modify the rendering process in such a way that it will write its intermediate results to disk instead of keeping it in memory.

This may mean that you can use the BMP format and write bit by bit to the disk as described in [the answer provided by Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73318783/1554195) (ok, in larger chunks, not really each single bit …), or you write an intermediate format of your own, or you allocate disk memory as cache memory.

But when your current rendering process finishes without an OOME, writing the resulting image to disk cannot be the real issue; only when writing would mean that the given data structure has to be converted again into a particular format, this could cause an issue (for example, the renderer returns a byte array holding the image as BMP, but the output should be a JPEG – in that case, you may have to hold the image in memory twice, and that could cause the OOME).

But without knowing details about what `panel.logic.Calculate()` and `panel.paint()` are really doing (in detail!), the question is difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you can assign more memory to JVM by Config -xmx on jvm parameters.
Second, Use Lazy-Load Strategy. you can try to split the image and every image splited is loaded when it display on the panel.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can take the following steps:

1. Downsize the image
2. Change image format
3. Assign more memory to JVM

Comment: None of these answers the question. For argument's sake assume the image will not be able to be fully stored in memory